# How to pass :id to jquery sortable function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am new to Jquery. Have a problem when passing parameter to Jquery function. 
My application has nested resources.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
```

And route is

```
sort_votes_post POST   /posts/:id/sort_votes(.:format)    posts#sort_votes
```

Sortable function is

```
$(function() {  
$("#sortable").sortable({
    update: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: $('#sortable').sortable('serialize'),
            url: '/posts/[not sure how to pass :id here]/sort_votes'})
    }
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

No idea how to pass :id to the url option.

Comment: Is it something you can access from your Javascript code?

Comment: maybe show your html - if there is way to put the id in the dom element (f.e. with the data attribute) that could be your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is in the asset pipeline I'm not sure you can because pipeline is precompiled so any dynamic details won't work.

It's a little hacky but I'd suggest passing a variable from the view so add before your application.js is added

```
<script>
   var url = [your url]
</script>
```

then in js

```
$(function() {  
$("#sortable").sortable({
    update: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: $('#sortable').sortable('serialize'),
            url: url
    }
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```